# Using gtsummary in R to display multiple logistic regressions in one table

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gtsummary

I need to display multiple logistic regressions in the same table and as I use `gtsummary` tables elsewhere in the document I am wondering if there is an idiomatic way of doing it with `gtsummary`? The data are univariate logistic regression results on the different factors in one column as well as multivariate logistic regressions on the same factors, displayed side by side.

Consider the following example as illustration using the `trial` dataset:

```r
library(gtsummary)

mdls <- list()
for (stage in levels(trial$stage)) {
  mdls[[stage]] <- list(
    uv = glm(I(stage == stage) ~ death, data = trial, family = "binomial"), 
    mv = glm(I(stage == stage) ~ death + age, data = trial, family = "binomial")
  )
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a table that looks something like this (invented data):

[image: desired output table]

Any pointers and how to achieve this, whether which `gtsummary` functions to use, or how to assemble the data to feed to `gtsummary`, or if I should forgo `gtsummary` for this and "build the table manually" with `gt`?

I have tried various "hacky" approaches, like creating indivdual tables for each regression, dropping all rows except the relevant one, change the row characteristic and then `tbl_stack()` and `tbl_merge()` to a final table. It works but it's not pretty. Similarly I have tried manually crafting a tibble to feed to `tbl_summary()` that looks correct which also works but is equally ugly. These solutions end up being a lot more complex than simply building the table with `gt` and then style the same as `gtsummary`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table `univ` for the univariate regressions using `tbl_uvregression` (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtsummary/versions/1.2.0/topics/tbl_uvregression))

And then create a table `multiv` with the multivariable regression using `tbl_regression` (see [here](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_regression.html))

Then merge these two tables using `tbl_merge`:

`table <- tbl_merge(tbls = list(univ, multiv), tab_spanner = c("**Univariable**", "**Multivariable**"))`

This should place the univariate and multivariate results next to each other in one table. Try if this works!